# Cordova. Email a pdf generated by jsPDF

Tags: cordova, email, pdf, mobile, jspdf

When I try to email a pdf generated by pdf in the same format as this:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.text(0, 0, 'Hello World!');
var pdfBase64 = pdf.output('datauristring');

window.plugin.email.open({
  to: ['to@email.com'],
  subject: 'New PDF!',
  body: 'Hi there, here is that new PDF you wanted!',
  isHTML: false,
  attachments: [pdfBase64]
});`
```

It opens up the email app correctly but then gives me an error that the pdf could not be attached. Does anyone know the reasoning behind this? This is done using jsPDF and the cordova email composer plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this. So you have to split the datauri based on commas then append the string base64 in front of it before joining the elements of the array. I did something like this.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'From within Cordova.');
var uristring = doc.output('datauristring');
var uristringparts = uristring.split(',');
uristringparts[0] = "base64:" + escape('sample.pdf') + "//";

var moddeduristring =  uristringparts.join("");
return moddeduristring;
```

The email pdf is successfully attached after doing it this way. I hope this helps anyone who is looking into the same problem.